# Serializing two objects within the same JSON and then deserializing them from the incoming string through Redis

Tags: java, json, serialization, redis, jackson

We are having some issues with jackson at my development team.

**Some non-important context**
We are pretty new with jackson and we had several issues over the past, but we always had tried to solve them with what we got over the internet and with past-problems solved over StackOverflow.

**Useful information**
We are parsing Java instanced objects to JSON so we can send them over redis as Strings and then get them through the pub/sub system to get them again as objects of the original type on the other end.

We have 2 fields where in each one of them represents different objects:

```
Data: a ChannelMessage object.
String senderName, message;
Enum:ServerType serverType;

Metadata: a RedisMetadata object.
String id, channelName, serverId;
Enum:MessageType type;
```

So our JSON should look something near this:

```
{
  "data": {
    "senderName": "PixelDev1729",
    "message": "asd",
    "serverType": "HUB"
  },
  "metadata": {
    "id": "1bba40f5-74ed-4ab8-ad81-83078ac11421",
    "channelName": "global-chat",
    "serverId": "b4409522-6a97-47f5-ad75-661ed86c52e8",
    "type": "SEND"
  }
}
```

**Several headaches**
We've tried using ObjectNodes writing values as String from the object.

We got a really messed up JSON string with lots of escapes (backslashes).

```
{"data":"{\"senderName\":\"PixelDev1729\",\"message\":\"asd\",\"serverType\":\"HUB\"}","metadata":"{\"id\":\"e0f77d09-cafa-4ff5-b553-0f0dc4bb76e3\",\"cha|
```

nnelName":"global-chat","serverId":"9f10cf0b-d3eb-4804-98aa-92d747d75f5e","type":"SEND"}"}

1. "No string-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from string value (Colum: 1, Line: 1)." in which from my expertise I can say the JSON string Jackson is getting is invalid.

So different approach...

Using `jsonString.replaceAll("^\"|\"$|\\\\", "");` to the same string we got first.

Resulting on an almost valid JSON but still invalid since we got some double quotes missing.

{"data":**"**{"senderName":"wasmake","message":"sadasdas","serverType":"VALHEIM"}**"**,"metadata":**"**{"id":"410c429c-06a4-466a-bce2-5edd63fabe17",|
"channelName":"global-chat","serverId":"640d01c3-5b13-4dcf-84bc-1d6b2987b333","type":"SEND"}**"**}

2. Unexpected character ('s' (code 115)): was expecting comma to separate Object entries

The double quotes doing weird things with our first field from data "**S**enderName".

CODE:

How we are serializing the object to JSON with jackson to send the message through Redis:
(https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/8813159/104827760-06717600-5827-11eb-8cd6-48554db93c49.png)

How we are trying to deserialize the JSON with jackson to get the object from the message we get from redis:
(https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/8813159/104827779-45073080-5827-11eb-84fc-47673c395b69.png)

The RedisMetadata class:
(https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/8813159/104827795-5cdeb480-5827-11eb-9595-c9326ca59e3f.png)

Console log:

(https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/8813159/104827799-66681c80-5827-11eb-8801-4c107df0dcb6.png)

(https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/8813159/104827801-6d8f2a80-5827-11eb-9170-80635c74110f.png)

We would really appreciate a helping hand since we've tried everything and with no luck,
thanks in advance!

Comment: For future reference, please do not post images of code; copy/paste it into your question instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is right there[image: The serializing part]

as you see, the data and metadata values are converted to String and then set into the main ObjectNode.

The problem with that is that when unserialized it is converted into a String value(I don't know how it is called actually) not actually a tree form of the value and that can't be deserialized with `ObjectMapper#treeToValue`. The solution is to convert the value into an ObjectNode with `ObjectMapper#valueToTree` and set it with `ObjectNode#set(String, JsonNode)`.

The other solution is to change the deserialization part, instead of trying to convert it directly with `ObjectMapper#treeToValue` use `ObjectMapper#readValue`.